# failed spark job leaves no history

Tags: logging, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

When I use spark-submit, all successfully completed jobs leaves plenty history afterwards. When a job fails, all log seems lost. from the history link, you see

Application application_1444757668999_0004 not found.

from the application link, you see the logs links, but they lead to

java.lang.Exception: Unknown container. Container either has not started or has already completed or doesn't belong to this node at all.

The only clue I have is in nohup.out, because I ran spark-submit under nohup. That log indicates executors start to die out

ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 4

How can I get yarn to leave logs intact so I can debug?

Comment: There is also global-like log files residing in `$SPARK_HOME/logs/` and also equivalent for YARN. E.g. driver logs are in `spark-foo-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-machine.out`. The files are pretty bloated, but still better than nothing.

Comment: I am using EMR and I don't see these directories you are pointing out. The right solution for this is still find how to get Spark history server to retain history in the event of a job failure. Anyone knows how?

Answer (score 0):

Spark submit submits an application not a job. You probably checking application history in YARN. In the case application is failed to start, you naturally will not see any history there.

You can try to submit in the **client** mode, so that it would be the same cluster for Spark jobs, but the Spark driver will be living locally and you can access the logs to check the reason of failure to start.

In the case a specific spark job failed with in an application, an application submission should not show any error, and you will be able to see all application information in the YARN UI.